# La página 114.545.215.150 ha rechazado la conexión

Tags: php, apache

Hola tengo una sencilla aplicación web en php, la cual quiero poder acceder desde cualquier lugar de internet de forma remota, ya abrí el puerto, no tengo ningun firewall ni antivirus, ya configure el xampp.
Y me sale que la página a rechazado la conexión. Alguien me ayuda por favor ??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En qué puerto escucha Apache?

Comment: ¿Es posible que tu compañia utilice CGNAT?

Comment: Como bien comenta @Xerif muchos proveedores de servicio bloquean el acceso de puertos por debajo de 1024. ¿Has verificado eso?

Comment: Ya pedi que abran el puerto y lo escaneo y me sale abierto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que no estas utilizando los puertos predeterminados, yo también estoy trabajando con un xampp que no está utilizando los puertos por defecto (porque están ocupados por el sistema) y para acceder a mi web de apache tengo que colocar la siguiente ruta

```
192.168.22.150:8080
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenta añadirle a la IP dos puntos y un puerto, prueba todos los puertos que tengas

Comment: Pruebo con la ip publica y el puerto que configure el xampp y sale lo mismo.

Comment: prueba a poner los puertos como yo, el principal 8080 y el secundario 4433